# exited with non-zero exit status 32: mount: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sdb7

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I have a laptop hard disk which had dual boot of Ubuntu and Windows. Now I want to use it as an external disk. I used 2.5" case an used the USB cable to mount but it is unable to mount the ubuntu file system. its mounting windows partitions but not ubuntu.

I don't know what is the problem. I don't want to delete the data from ubuntu.

[image: error message]

When I plug the disk it is showing the above image error.

And when I try to run:

```
sudo fsck /dev/sdb7
sudo fsck /dev/sdb7
```

I am getting the following errors:

[image: errors in terminal]

Is there anything I can do to solve these issues?

Comment: Could you transcript your terminal errors into your question? It will make your question clearer.

Comment: What are you using to mount ext4 partition on Windows? Are you using Ext2fsd? Have you unmounted the partition from Ext2fsd before booting to Ubuntu? if you can provide anymore information that would be a lot help

Answer (score 2):

If your hard drive isn't making noise and isn't broken, you need to find its absolute path.

```
lsblk
```

You need to find the process which is still being used.

```
ps -aux | grep /dev/sdXNumber
```

Take the first number which is the process ID and kill it.

```
sudo kill -9 ID_NUMBER_PROCESS
```

Retry to unmount the disk.

```
sudo unmount /dev/sdXNumbert
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sdxn
```

Replace the `xn` with your partition name
In your case this should be

```
sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sdb7
```

Comment: I executed sudo e2fsck -f -b 32768 -y /dev/sdb7 and i got the following errors & no results.
e2fsck 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 25714176 blocks
The physical size of the device is 25652992 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort? yes


/dev/sdb7: ***** FILE SYSTEM WAS MODIFIED *****

Comment: I think you should update the question with this additional information that my answer didn't work